# Can't install/compile asciidoctor-mathematical gem

Tags: ruby, macos, ubuntu, asciidoc, asciidoctor

On OSX I have, as per instructions, `brew install glib gdk-pixbuf cairo pango cmake` and installed the fonts and even tried the `brew link gettext --force` (but the compilation error seems unrelated to that anyway...)

Here's what occurs:

```
$ sudo gem install asciidoctor-mathematical
... output omitted
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.48.1/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32:
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.48.1/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:422:3: error: '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' declared as an array with a negative size
G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.48.1/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:103: note: expanded from macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
#define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [lasem_overrides.o] Error 1
```

Also had a go on Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo gem install asciidoctor-mathematical
... output omitted
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:635:0,
             from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mathematical-1.6.7/ext/mathematical/mtex2MML/src/../deps/uthash/uthash.h:29,
             from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mathematical-1.6.7/ext/mathematical/mtex2MML/src/environment.h:4,
             from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mathematical-1.6.7/ext/mathematical/mtex2MML/src/mtex2MML.h:12,
             from lasem_overrides.c:5:
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mathematical-1.6.7/ext/mathematical/mtex2MML/src/../deps/uthash/../strdup/strdup.h:24:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__extension__’
strdup(const char *str);
^
make: *** [lasem_overrides.o] Error 1
```

Out of my depth. Would love to get it working on either platform. Any troubleshooting suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I met same problem on Ubuntu 16.04
It troubleshooted to following command.

```
sudo MATHEMATICAL_SKIP_STRDUP=1 gem install mathematical
```